# How to pass value to controller through URL in YII framework of php?

Tags: php, url, yii

This is the code

```
 <a type="button" class="btn btn-info" href="<?php echo CHtml::normalizeUrl(array(Yii::app()->controller->getId() . '/createStudent')); ?>">Add Student</a>
```

I want to pass class ID to the controller create student along with the url. The class id is in the variable

```
<?php $classId = $selectedSchoolClass->getId();?>
```

Comment: is this Yii1 or Yii2? add relevant tags only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you have almost did it, you should only concatenate it with the `&` caracter and send the new param/data with the URL:

```
Yii::app()->controller->getId() . '/createStudent&classId='.$classId;
```

From the controller you can receive the data with:

```
$request = Yii::$app->request;
$classId = $request->get('classId');
// equivalent to: $classId = isset($_GET['classId']) ? $_GET['classId'] : null;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use the class `Html` to create `<a></a>` tags.

```
<?= Html::a('Add Student', 
        ['createStudent', 'id' => $classId], 
        ['type' => 'button', 'class' => 'btn btn-info'] ) ?>
```